# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Page Route Ambiguous Match Exception

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, routes, startup, razor-pages

In razor pages I give the user an option to compare up to 3 products.
It works for 2 correctly, but when I open the link for 3 product It gives me "AmbiguousMatchException"

My Route in Startup.cs is like below:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Compare", "compare/{ProductCode1}(vs){ProductCode2}(vs){ProductCode3}");
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Compare", "compare/{ProductCode1}(vs){ProductCode2}");
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Compare", "compare/{ProductCode1}");
```

It handles 
"/compare/p1" for 1st product
"/compare/p1(vs)p2"  for the p1 and p2

but raises error for url below however I defined it on the first route
"/compare/p1(vs)p2(vs)p3"

and the error is funny:

```
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
/Compare
/Compare
/Compare
```

It's correct, I defined this page for all 3 routes, what's the matter with 3rd product??

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by replacing all routes to one and split that one parameter to all product codes.